# Add row with value when value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below sheet

```
value1 | value2
001    | car
001    | car1
002    | moto
002    | moto2
003    | ship
```

I want to insert a blank row when the "value1" changes like this

```
value1 | value2
001    | car
001    | car1
       |
002    | moto
002    | moto2
       |
003    | ship
```

And for this I use this code which works fine:

```
Sub blankRows()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Range("E" & i).Value <> Range("E" & i - 1).Value Then Rows(i).Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

What I want is not only to add a blank row, but to the start of the blank row to insert also 10 asterisks. Like this

```
    value1 | value2
    001    | car
    001    | car1
********** |
    002    | moto
    002    | moto2
********** |
    003    | ship
********** |
```

Can you please alter my code above to also add 10 asterisks at the blank row it inserts?

Comment: Hmm add `cells(i,1).value="*********"` assuming column A.

Comment: @Raystafarian sigh. Made me test it. What about you?

Comment: Nope, I hadn't. Needs an `end if` though.

Comment: well I added the code you both suggested but it does not work correctly. It adds asterisks to all the fields at column A. I want only to add asterisks only to the blank lines which the previous macro adds

Comment: lol my fault. Thought it was obvious but you need to nest it within the if statement XD Edit: you need an `end if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub blankRows()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Range("E" & i).Value <> Range("E" & i - 1).Value Then
    Rows(i).Insert
    Cells(i, 1) = "**********"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Uh OP said column A XD

Comment: Stealing my thunder =P

Comment: @findwindow if you'd like to post an answer, go for it. I'm pretty sure I can delete a community wiki. It just didn't seem like the OP was getting the `end if`

Comment: nah, just pulling your chain ^_^

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not necessary as Subtotal will achieve much the same, with a little help, and offers automatic grouping, which may or may not be appreciated.

Assuming `value1` is in A1, select the two columns, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, At each change in: `value1`, Use function: `Count`, Add subtotal to: `value1` only checked, check Replace current subtotals and Summary below data), OK. Filter the inserted column to select for Text Filters, Contains..., `c`, OK and in B1:

```
**********
```

Copy down to suit, delete ColumnA and, if desired, last occupied row.